# Text container width rendered in different sizes in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Why is the container width rendered in different sizes in Chrome and Firefox?
Image sample.
Chrome:  the rendered width is 681.273

[image]
FireFox: the rendered width is 685.8499
[image]

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Arvo';
    max-width: 824px;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    word-break: break-word;
    width: max-content;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left:20px;
    outline: red solid 1px;
    color: black;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

p { 



}
```

```html
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arvo&display=swap');
</style>
<div id="div-main-con">
  <p>
    What are we A team? No, no, no. We're a chemical mixture that makes 
  </p>
</div>

<p id="temp-con">

</p>


<script differ>
elm = document.getElementById('div-main-con')

document.getElementById('temp-con').innerText = `the below container width is  ${elm.getBoundingClientRect().width}`

</script>
```

Open the below link in both browsers you’ll see the difference.

[Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwf3jga5/1/)

Is there any way to render in the same width in both browsers?

Answer (score 1):

### **Reasons** for the problem:

- **Different default styles**: Both Chrome and Firefox have their own different default styles for HTML elements.
- **Differences in the way of handling css for both the browser**: Both have their own rendering engines due to which they may be handling css properties in different way.

### **Solutions to the problem**

- **Use a css `reset`**: Css reset is a set of styles that remove the default styles of the browser, [what is css reset](https://shorturl.at/cdJPU).
- **Use CSS vendor prefix**: They are prefixes to css properties that is used so that the css properties supports that browser, [CSS vendor prefixing](https://shorturl.at/cdJPU)